# How can I test a Keras model on a group of images?

Tags: python, keras

I have the following in Keras:

```
train_data = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)
validation_data = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)
test_data = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)

train_features = np.zeros(shape=(number_of_training_samples,16,16,512))
train_labels = np.zeros(shape=(number_of_training_samples))

train_generator = train_data.flow_from_directory(
    train_directory,
    target_size=(512,512),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    shuffle=True)

i = 0
for inputs_batch, labels_batch in train_generator:
    features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
    train_features[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size] = features_batch
    train_labels[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size] = labels_batch
    i += 1
    if i * batch_size >= number_of_training_samples:
        break

train_features = np.reshape(train_features, (number_of_training_samples,16*16*512))

validation_features = np.zeros(shape=(number_of_validation_samples,16,16,512))
validation_labels = np.zeros(shape=(number_of_validation_samples))

validation_generator = validation_data.flow_from_directory(
    validation_directory,
    target_size=(512,512),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    shuffle=False)

i = 0
for inputs_batch, labels_batch in validation_generator:
    features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
    validation_features[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size] = features_batch
    validation_labels[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size] = labels_batch
    i += 1
    if i * batch_size >= number_of_validation_samples:
        break

validation_features = np.reshape(validation_features, (number_of_validation_samples,16*16*512))

test_generator = test_data.flow_from_directory(
    test_directory,
    target_size=(512,512),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    shuffle=False)

# define the Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) model
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(1024,activation='relu',input_dim=16*16*512))
model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

# compile the model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01),
    metrics=['acc'])

# fit the model to the data
history = model.fit(train_features,
    train_labels,
    epochs=1,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_data=(validation_features,validation_labels))

# save the model
model.save('model.h5')
```

I tried to test the model on a group of images, as follows:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(test_directory):
    for file in files:
        img = cv2.imread(root + '/' + file)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (512,512))
        img_class = model.predict_classes(img)
        prediction = img_class[0]
```

I'm however getting:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have shape (None, 131072) but got array with shape (512, 512)
```

On the line:

```
img_class = model.predict_classes(img)
```

Why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: Your first problem is that you define your model's input size as `16*16*512` while you are trying to feed it in your test with image of shape `(512, 512)`.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I'm trying to do "transfer learning", and have the following: conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape=(512,512,3)). I used "input_dim=16*16*512" because the input to the classifier would be that dimension. It seems that I might be confusing things here? What changes do you recommend to the code?

Comment: So if I get your point correctly, at first you should feed your `img` data into your `conv_base ` which is your `VGG16` model and then feed it's out put in to your `model` ( now you are feeding your `img` into your `model`).

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. But, not sure what to enter in order to find the model's prediction accuracy on the "test" data

Comment: I think my previous comment exactly address this issue. In the last part of your code, after loading your test image, instead of this line:`img_class = model.predict_classes(img)` feed your image into your `conv_base` which is your VGG16 model for example like `out_1= conv_base.predict(img)` And then feed `out_1` intor your model like `img_class = model.predict_classes(out_1)`

Comment: Hi @Simplicity, I'm from the Vasern Support. I received your email about the question this morning. But I am unable to reply to your email address as "Address not found". Other people sending you email might have this trouble too.